# Flex Builder: Asset file or directory name cannot be more than 100 bytes long

Tags: testing, mobile, compiler-errors, flash-builder

Today i want to test my Mobile App on my Samsung Galaxy device. I did that before and it was working great.

Today it stops working, Flash Builder "says" that there is an error:
"Asset file or directory name cannot be more than 100 bytes long"

What can I do about this? Any idea what's going on?
I asked it here because I cannot find a solution on the net.

**EDIT:**
Exact error is:
Error occurred while packaging the application:

Asset file or directory name cannot be more than 100 bytes long. Error occurred for : dataimagepng;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAzAAAAJECAYAAADJzMF4AAAgAElEQVR4nNy9eZCt513f+cixHWF339vdt2v6+l9OWsvpvurV2yVpIMSQ.URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was a weird link file (*.url) (added) in the package explorer with a very long name in default package folder as well in the bin-debug folder.

dataimagepng;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAzAAAAJECAYAAADJzMF4AAAgAElEQVR4nNy9eZCt513f+cixHWF339vdt2v6+l9OWsvpvurV2yVpIMSQ......URL

Strange, by removing these files the problem is solved.
Anybody any idea where these files came from?